# How to save related classes in Realm?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I recently started using `Realm`. First it is clear, if you store one class, that is, one object. But when you want to store classes that have custom types in the fields, and they have the same thing.

That is:

```
class Dog extend RealmObject{
private int count;
private Cat cat;

// геттеры и сеттеры
}

class Cat extend RealmObject{
private int count;
private RealmList<Cow> cowList;

// геттеры и сеттеры
}

class Cow extend RealmObject{
private int count;
private Horse horse;

// геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

So, to save this in the database wrote a bunch of lines:

```
public void setChatsList(final ChatsModel chatsModel) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {

            ChatsModel realmChats = realm.createObject(ChatsModel.class);
            Response realmResponse = realm.createObject(Response.class);
            Item realmItem = realm.createObject(Item.class);
            Message realmMessage = realm.createObject(Message.class);
            Attachment realmAttachment = realm.createObject(Attachment.class);
            Video realmVideo = realm.createObject(Video.class);

            Response response = chatsModel.getResponse();
            RealmList<Item> items = new RealmList<>();
            Integer itemCount = response.getCount();
            RealmList<Item> itemList = response.getItems();

            if (itemList != null) {
                for (Item item : itemList) {
                    Message message = item.getMessage();

                    realmMessage.setId(message.getId());
                    realmMessage.setDate(message.getDate());
                    realmMessage.setOut(message.getOut());
                    realmMessage.setUserId(message.getUserId());
                    realmMessage.setReadState(message.getReadState());
                    realmMessage.setTitle(message.getTitle());
                    realmMessage.setBody(message.getBody());
                    realmMessage.setRandomId(message.getRandomId());
                    RealmList<Attachment> attachments = message.getAttachments();
                    RealmList<Attachment> attachmentList = new RealmList<>();

                    if (attachments != null) {
                        for (Attachment attachment : attachments) {
                            String type = attachment.getType();
                            Video video = attachment.getVideo();

                            realmVideo.setAccessKey(video.getAccessKey());
                            realmVideo.setCanAdd(video.getCanAdd());
                            realmVideo.setCanEdit(video.getCanEdit());
                            realmVideo.setComments(video.getComments());
                            realmVideo.setDate(video.getDate());
                            realmVideo.setDescription(video.getDescription());
                            realmVideo.setDuration(video.getDuration());
                            realmVideo.setId(video.getId());
                            realmVideo.setOwnerId(video.getOwnerId());
                            realmVideo.setPhoto130(video.getPhoto130());
                            realmVideo.setPhoto320(video.getPhoto320());
                            realmVideo.setPhoto640(video.getPhoto640());
                            realmVideo.setPlatform(video.getPlatform());
                            realmVideo.setTitle(video.getTitle());
                            realmVideo.setViews(video.getViews());

                            realmAttachment.setType(type);
                            realmAttachment.setVideo(realmVideo);

                            attachmentList.add(realmAttachment);
                        }
                        realmMessage.setAttachments(attachmentList);
                    }

                    realmResponse.getItems().add(item);
                }
            }

            realmResponse.setCount(itemCount);
            realmChats.setResponse(realmResponse);
        }
    });
}
```

Agree that for one task rows are too much. And it seems to me that I'm doing it wrong

Question: How to do it correctly and how to shorten my method, tell me?

Comment: Apart from the `attachmentList` which looks iffy and that the Realm instance is not closed after done with it, it looks ok

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, but what's wrong with `attachmentList`?

Comment: `realmMessage` is a managed object, but `attachmentList` is an unmanaged RealmList. Should be `realmMessage.getAttachments().addAll(attachmentList)`.

Comment: that is, create a table for each class? Although I do not directly contact them directly

Comment: ...huh? I never said anything like that

Comment: Does not `createObject()` create a table?

Comment: it creates an **object**

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing some finer details, but it looks like you are just mapping the response 1:1. Is there any reason you cannot use it directly?

```
ChatsModel realmChats = realm.createObject(ChatsModel.class);
realmChats.addResponse(chatsModel.getItems());
```

Realm will automatically convert an un-managed list to a managed one.

Comment: Because when I do this:

    `ChatsModel realmChats = realm.createObject(ChatsModel.class);
    realmChats.setResponse(chatsModel.getResponse());`

I get this error:

   ` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'value' is not a valid managed object.`

Comment: and if I write the way I wrote above in the question, it works correctly